# OrientDB - Get network at level 2

Tags: graph, orientdb

I'm working for a big professional social network and we are starting to check if OrientDB meets our requirements in terms of Social Graph. For now on, we have managed to deploy a cluster of 10 nodes, setup backups and restore and populate all of our data from MongoDB to OrientDB with no major issues.
Our  data model is :

- vertices :

  - **Profile**
  - **Company**
  - **Job**
  - **Publication**
  - ...
- edges :

  - **Followed** : one profile can follow another profile or a company
  - **Applied** : one profile can apply to a job
  - **Posted** : one profile can post some publication on the network
  - ...

What I want to know is :

1. How to get all people connected to one given profile at depth 1 or 2. I've tried something like `SELECT out('Followed').out('Followed') as friend FROM 14:4` where 14:4 is a Profile object. Unfortunately, it gives me Profiles as well as Companies since a Profile can "Followed" a Company. How can I filter to get Profiles only ? I've tried `SELECT out('Followed').out('Followed') as friend FROM 14:4 where @class = 'Profile'` but it does not work :( Should I have multiple edge classes (FollowedProfile and FollowedCompany) to ease queries ?
2. When a Profile creates an account using another Social Network (Facebook, Google, ...) we are storing his existing contacts and match them with our database so we can say "Profile A is connected to Profile B thanks to Facebook". How should I represent that in OrientDB ? An attribute on the edge or a dedicated edge class ?
3. Last one is : how can I get the shortest path between two Profiles ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try with

```
SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(out('Followed').out('Followed')) as friend FROM 14:4) Where @class='Profile'
```

2) I think An attribute (thanks) on the edge is better

3) You can use shortestPath function (http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Functions.html) :

Example:

```
select shortestPath(#8:32, #8:10, 'BOTH')
```

Comment: 1/ I've tested this but it does not work : it does not return anything :( See http://s8.postimg.org/4o4fy2mxh/Capture_d_cran_2015_02_10_10_19_33.png So I have tested a solution with a different edge class : 'Connected'. The query becomes `SELECT distinct(value) as slug from (select expand(out('Connected').out('Connected').slug) as slugs FROM 14:4)`

Comment: Hum... I had to use the `expand` function to make this first query working : `SELECT distinct(slug) as slug FROM (SELECT expand(out('Followed').out('Followed')) FROM 14:4) where @class = 'Profile'`

Comment: I added expand function

Comment: Thanks :) For the 3rd question, I'm also concerned that shortestPath would  return path using wrong edges. For exemple, assuming that `Px` is the Profile with id x and `Cx` the Company with id x, if I have the following graph `Pa -> Pb -> Pc -> Pd` and `Pa -> Ca -> Pd`, the shortest path between Pa and Pd would be using Ca. My goal is to help users get in touch with each others : using company in the path does not fit my requirements :( How can I use `shortestPath` with a constraint on the Edge class. In my case, Profile are `Connected` to other Profiles and `Followed` Companies.

Comment: So, I'd like to have something like `shortestPath(#8:32, #8:10, 'BOTH', 'Connected')`. Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: You can add a weight attribuite on yours edges then you can use djikstra function. I advise you to use orientdb google group to have more responses